# Что это за класс org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists

Tags: android-studio

Как и где найти этот класс org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists , выдаёт ошибку NoClassDefFoundError со ссылкой на этот класс?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот класс генерирует вам ошибку. Проблема в другом.

Comment: @dmtr А как тогда эту ошибку исправить, подскажите,пожалуйста?